# Query annotation not working for max(id)

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-jpa, jpql, jhipster

I have a domain object GenJournal and it has an "id" member (Long) that's auto-generated. I also have a JPA repository that I've added ...

```
@Query("select coalesce(max(u.id), 0) from GenJournal u")
Long getMaxId();
```

The method getMaxId() returns zero or null before I added coalesce. I have two rows in my database with ids 1 and 2. Can anyone help me determine why this doesn't work?

I'm trying to get the latest or max id so that I can use the find method after to return the most recent GenJournal object in my service class.

I'm stumped and really need some options or strategy to determine why this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You could use "Native Query" feature by passing nativeQuery = true param into @Query annotation like this

@Query("select coalesce(max(u.id), 0) from Gen_Journal_Table u", NativeQuery = true)
Long getMaxId();

Comment: I was successful using the nativeQuery option, however my syntax was: @Query(nativeQuery=true, value="select coalesce(max(u.id),0) from gen_journal u") Long getMaxId()

Comment: The idea is you can execute a native query outside the code to verify the result. So in your case, your code pointed to difference db.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was two-fold. First I was getting null without the use of "coalesce". That caused me to think that this didn't work. When I adopted the use of "coalesce" I didn't realize that my table had no records and was returning the zero (0). My table in the production profile did have two records and I was expecting an id of 2.

I was manually checking the wrong database and setting expectations that were incorrect.